# How to mock global variable in Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, google-apps-script, testing, jestjs

I will try to be brief and to the point. In our school we use Google Sheets as a class book. I have a script that counts the absences of individual students. The script is written in Google Apps Scripts (GAS), but the purpose of the application and even GAS are irrelevant to this question.

I'm currently trying to rewrite my old code and try to implement Jest unit testing. So my question will be simple. How can I mock a global variable that I call inside the function under test?

Here I paste the part of the code that introduces the global variables:

```
const absenceFileId = "some_string"
const teachersFileId = "some_string"
const studentGroupsId = "some_string"
const classbookFolderId = "some_string"

// STATE
let teachers = {}
let groups = {}
let subjectCounter = {}
let errors = []
let students = {}

function setupStateVariables() {
    teachers = getTeachers(removeEmptyRowsAndHeader(getValuesArray(teachersFileId, 0, 1, 1, 50, 3)));
    groups = getGroups(removeEmptyRowsAndHeader(getValuesArray(studentGroupsId, 0, 1, 1, 400, 6)))
    subjectCounter = createSubjectCounter(removeEmptyRowsAndHeader(getValuesArray(studentGroupsId, 1, 1, 1, 200, 4)))
}
```

Subsequently, I need to update the global variable `subjectCounter` inside the function:

```
function updateSubjectCounter(group, schoolClass, subject) {
    if (!(subject in subjectCounter[schoolClass])) {
        return
    }
    if (group) {
        subjectCounter[schoolClass][subject][group] += 1
    } else {
        let keys = Object.keys(subjectCounter[schoolClass][subject])
        if (keys.length > 1) {
            for (let key of keys) {
                subjectCounter[schoolClass][subject][key] += 1
            }
        } else {
            subjectCounter[schoolClass][subject][null] += 1
        }
    }
}
```

I have the previous code in the `main.js` module.

I export the function for testing as follows. If statement is here due to GAS enviroment.:

```
if (typeof module !== 'undefined') {
    module.exports = {
        "getTeachers": getTeachers,
        "getGroups": getGroups,
        "createSubjectCounter": createSubjectCounter,
        "updateSubjectCounter": updateSubjectCounter
    }
}
```

For testing, I use the `main.test.js` module, which looks like this:

```
const main = require('./main');

test("Test funkce updateSubjectCounter", () => {
    main.updateSubjectCounter("", "a", "IFM")
    expect(subjectCounter).toEqual({something})
```

The question is how to mock the global variable `subjectCounter` in this test?

**EDIT**: I am using local enviroment with NodeJS for testing.

Comment: Can you explain mock?

Comment: you probably should not use global variables. I consider them a code smell. and they make testing hard - as you have probably experienced

Comment: Read TheMasters comments on lazyloading. I use a similar technique to refresh my global variables with both properties service and spreadsheet based hash tables

Comment: @Cooper "mock objects are simulated objects that mimic the behaviour of real objects in controlled ways" this is wikipedia definition. And I think I used the word mock in same way. In need to replace subjectCounter, that is created by function, which need GAS services, but GAS services is not available at the local enviroment.

Comment: @YAMM Yes, you're right, but for GAS scripts it's a pretty convenient way to store state that many functions need to access.

Comment: If you wish to use global variables just insure that they are initialized on each function call to their updated value